# How to plot color distribution of HSV image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a dataset of images representing human skin.
How do I plot the skin color distribution in HSV color space and YCbCr color space.
However, I'd like ignore the "value" or "brightness" in both color spaces and analyze rest of the layers.

The below is the code I am using to plot the distribution for YCbCr, but don't understand what is happening. Can anyone please explain what is going on and how to do it more efficiently?

```
chroma = zeros(256);
cb = imycc(:,:,2);
cb = reshape(cb, 1, numel(cb));
cb = round(cb);

cr = imycc(:,:,3);
cr = reshape(cr, 1, numel(cr));
cr = round(cr);

for i = 1:length(cb)
   chroma(cb(i), cr(i)) = chroma(cb(i), cr(i)) + 1;
end
surf(chroma)
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "plot the color distribution"? What would be the ideal output? You could plot CB vs. CR, or just display a histogram of S. Depends what you want to learn...

Comment: @chappjc can you please look into the new changes in the question

Comment: @lamcool I looked at your changes and posted an answer. Did my answer help or answer your question? This site functions when users vote on posts and accept answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a 2D histogram of the number of occurrences of a given CB-CR combination.

A faster way to do this is with `accumarray`:

```
chroma = accumarray([cb(:) cr(:)],1);
```

This does the same thing as your loop.  It adds one for each position in CB,CR space.

The code defines `chroma = zeros(256);` probably because the input image is `uint8`, with values ranging on [0,255]. If you want to respect this output size, add the size argument:

```
chroma = accumarray([cb(:) cr(:)],1,[intmax('uint8')+1 intmax('uint8')+1]);
```